# Delphi 7 MySQL5.7 mysql.pas libmysql.dll UTF8

Tags: mysql, delphi, utf-8

can any one tell / show me how interacting with libmysql.dll using mysql.pas
mysql 5.7 and Delphi 7 and working with utf8? 
example of code is appreciated? 
thanx
(English is my third language and i cannot speak English very well)

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: for j := 0 to mysql_num_fields(myRES) - 1 do
                          begin
                            aStr := aStr +'  '+ myROW^[j] ;
                          end;
                        Memo2.Lines.Add( aStr )  ;
                      end;
                  end;


//resultat on  Memo2.Lines.Add( aStr )  ;

  1  â´°  A  

  2  â´°  A  

  3  â´°  A  

  4  â´°  A  

  5  â´°  A

Comment: i have on database a table content a multi language data encoded with utf 8

Comment: I wrote a libmysql.dll wrapper myself [here](https://github.com/stijnsanders/DataLank/blob/master/LibMy.pas)

Comment: thank you @stijn-sanders, i well give it a try

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title is descriptive of the problem you're having or question you're asking. All you've done is repeated the information already in the tags and added the word *example*. Your title should be clear enough to have meaning and relevance to future readers who see it in a search result. Thanks

Comment: If you were hoping to get the Tafinagh letter YA (`ⴰ`), then you have "Mojibake".

Comment: yes @rick james that is correct but how do i use "mojibake" if it is tool or fix it if it is a problem ,  am trying to get a multi language data : Arabic French Japanese .....

Answer (score 0):

Read [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) and look for "Mojibake".

- The bytes to be stored need to be UTF-8-encoded. Fix this.
- The connection when INSERTing and SELECTing text needs to specify utf8 or utf8mb4. Fix this.
- The column needs to be declared `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4). Fix this.
- HTML should start with `<meta charset=UTF-8>`.

Then, depending what situation you have, fixing the data needs one of the actions [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases).

Arabic, French, and Japanese can all be handled by utf8.